# Put $n^2$ identical items in $n$ numbered boxes

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations, combinations

There are $n^2$ identical objects given to us. These objects are to be kept in $n$ numbered boxes $(1, 2, 3,\ldots,n)$. but every $i^{\text{th}}$ box must have at least $i$ of the items in it. Find the total number of ways.

So I have tried a bit:

First, I thought of the minimum number of items needed to be put in the boxes, i.e., $n(n+1)/2$. Then there are $n^2 - n(n+1)/2$ items left to be distributed in $n$ boxes. But now since all items are identical, there must be only one way of putting the remaining items in the boxes. so the answer should be $n(n+1)/2$. But I am wrong in something since the answer is $\, ^{(n^2-n-2)/2}C_ {(n-1)}$. Please help me with this.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference In short, putting dollar signs about each mathematical formula will get you half-way there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem, as you say, reduces to putting $\frac12(n^2-n)$ identical balls into $n$ labelled boxes. The "stars-and-bars" method counts the number of ways of putting $m$ identical balls into $n$ labelled boxes as $\binom{m+n-1}{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

To be found is the number of sums $k_1+\cdots+k_n=\frac12n(n-1)$ where the $k_i$ are nonnegative integers.

You can do this by means of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).